# Visual studio browse references source?

Tags: visual-studio

I remember being able to do this but I must have changed something as I can no longer view an external projects source even though the pdb is with the reference. I can step into external functions when debugging but I can't go to them using "Go to implementation/declaration"

Comment: It is not supposed to work, the .pdb is for the debugger only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work if you have a separate *class library Project* as a part of your Solution, and you added a reference to the ***Project***, not the compiled .dll.

You cannot step into a .dll when debugging.

It's all in how you add the reference.